# Print python os.urandom output on terminal

Tags: python

how can i print the output of `os.urandom(n)` in terminal?

I try to generate a SECRET_KEY with fabfile and will output the 24 bytes.

Example how i implement both variants in the python shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> out = os.urandom(24)
>>> out
'oS\xf8\xf4\xe2\xc8\xda\xe3\x7f\xc75*\x83\xb1\x06\x8c\x85\xa4\xa7piE\xd6I'
>>> print out
oS�������5*������piE�I
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you want is hex-encoded string, use [`binascii.a2b_hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) (or `hexlify`):

```
>>> out = 'oS\xf8\xf4\xe2\xc8\xda\xe3\x7f\xc75*\x83\xb1\x06\x8c\x85\xa4\xa7piE\xd6I'
>>> import binascii
>>> print binascii.hexlify(out)
6f53f8f4e2c8dae37fc7352a83b1068c85a4a7706945d649
```

Comment: Is this hex-encoded string equal to the byte version? To use it as a scret key in a Webapp?

Comment: @haengebruegge, No, they are not equal (`out != binascii.hexlify(out)`). I don't know what `webapp` means.

Comment: A website build with for example django or flask. They need both a secret key. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key or http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.secret_key

Answer (score 1):

To use just built-ins, you can get the integer value with `ord` and then convert that back to a hex number:

```
list_of_hex = [str(hex(ord(z)))[2:] for z in out]
print " ".join(list_of_hex)
```

If you just want the hex list, then the `str()` and `[2:]` are unnecessary

The output of this and the `hexify()` version are both type `str` and should work fine for the web app.

Comment: The `str()` is completely unnecessary - the `hex()` function already returns a str...